# Change modal height based on it's content

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm trying to create a modal scene for my phaser 3 project. here is my current code in `modal.js`:

```
class modal extends Phaser.Scene {

    // constructor
    constructor() {
        super("Modal");
    }

    preload() {
        this.load.image("header", "Assets/popUpTop.png");
        this.load.image("x", "Assets/x.png");
    }

    init(data) {
        this.modalName = data.modalName;
    }

    create() {
        // create a white rounded rectangle as modal background
        var bgGrafics = this.make.graphics();
        bgGrafics.fillStyle(0xffffff, 1);
        bgGrafics.fillRoundedRect(0, 0, gameConfig.width / 3, gameConfig.height / 1.7, 51);
        bgGrafics.generateTexture("modalBg", gameConfig.width / 3, gameConfig.height / 1.7);
        this.modalBg = this.add.sprite(gameConfig.width / 2, gameConfig.height / 2, "modalBg");
        
        this.modalBg.setScale(1.05);
        
        this.headerBg = this.add.image(0, 0, "header");
        this.headerBg.setScale((this.modalBg.width * 1.05 / this.headerBg.width), (1 + (0.05 * this.modalBg.height / this.headerBg.height)));
        
        this.closeBtn = new RoundedButton(this, 0, 0, 43, "x", 1.3, () => {this.close()}); // RoundedButton is a custom class that extends Phaser.GameObjects.Container
        this.add.existing(this.closeBtn);

        // help modal
        if(this.modalName === 'help') {
        // add content of help modal 
        }
        // profile modal
        else if(this.modalName === 'profile') {
        // add content of profile modal 
        }
        // confirm spin modal
        else if(this.modalName === 'spin') {
        // add content of confirm modal 
        }
        
        Phaser.Display.Align.In.TopRight(this.closeBtn, this.modalBg);
        Phaser.Display.Align.In.TopCenter( this.headerBg, this.modalBg );
    }

    close() {
        this.scene.stop('Modal');
        this.scene.run('PlayGame');
    }
}
```

as you can see in my code, I'm trying to add different contents to modal based on `modelName` but I couldn't find a way to change modal height based on it's content.
how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution is, to use the function `setWordWrapWidth` from gameObject `Phaser.GameObjects.TextStyle` *([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.TextStyle.html#setWordWrapWidth__anchor))* to limit the `width`, then setting the content of the `text` gameObject and finally getting and using the `height` property of the `text` gameObject.

With the `width` and `height` of the `text` gameObject *(calculated from Phaser)*, you can simply render the `graphics` object, with the correct size *(I also would add some padding)*. If you want/need to generate the texture, you would have to delete it each time, since the size might have changed.

**Here is a short demo:**
*(I'm generating the texture, since it is in the original code, but I would simply use the `graphics` gameObject.)*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

const TEXT_SHORT = 'Hello World.'.repeat(8);
const TEXT_LONG = TEXT_SHORT.repeat(2);

class Main extends Phaser.Scene {

    constructor() {
        super("Main");
    }

    create() {
        let buttonShortText = this.add.rectangle(10, 10, 80, 40, 0xcdcdcd)
            .setOrigin(0)
            .setInteractive()
            .on('pointerdown', () => this.scene.start('Modal', {
                name: 'SHORT',
                text: TEXT_SHORT,
                padding: 10,
                maxWidth: 200
            }));

        // x,y Position are not relevant since they will be change on align
        let helperLabel = this.add.text(0, 0, 'SHORT').setColor('#000000');

        Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center(helperLabel, buttonShortText);

        let buttonLongText = this.add.rectangle(100, 10, 80, 40, 0xcdcdcd)
            .setOrigin(0)
            .setInteractive()
            .on('pointerdown', () => this.scene.start('Modal', {
                name: 'SHORT',
                text: TEXT_LONG,
                padding: 20,
                maxWidth: 400
            }));

        // x,y Position are not relevant since they will be change on align
        let helperLabel2 = this.add.text(0, 0, 'LONG').setColor('#000000');

        Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center(helperLabel2, buttonLongText);
    }
}

class Modal extends Phaser.Scene {

    constructor() {
        super("Modal");
    }

    init(data) {
        this._name = data.name;
        this._text = data.text + '\n\nClick to Close';
        this._maxWidth = data.maxWidth;
        this._padding = data.padding;
    }

    create() {
        this.add.rectangle(0, 0, config.width, config.height, 0xcdcdcd, .5)
            .setOrigin(0)
            .setInteractive()
            .on('pointerdown', () => this.scene.start('Main'));

        // x,y Position are not relevant since they will be change on align
        this.content = this.add.text(0, 0, this._text).setColor('#000000');
        this.content.setWordWrapWidth(this._maxWidth - (2 * this._padding));
        this.content.setDepth(10);

        let bgHeight = this.content.height + (2 * this._padding);

        let graphics = this.make.graphics({ add: false });

        graphics.fillStyle(0xffffff);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, this._maxWidth, bgHeight, 0xffffff);

        // Remove the texture is it was generated and has a different size.
        if (this.textures.exists('bgModal')) {
            this.textures.remove('bgModal');
        }

        graphics.generateTexture('bgModal', this._maxWidth, bgHeight);

        this.bgImage = this.add.image(config.width / 2, config.height / 2, 'bgModal');

        // Center Text onto the Background
        Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center(this.content, this.bgImage);
    }
}

var config = {
    type: Phaser.CANVAS,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: [Main, Modal]
};

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```